# Can you do something ( an event) when you select a date with XamForms.Controls.Calendar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugins

I am using https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar currently on my app, I have an agenda view and a calendar view, when I click a date on the calendar I want to be able to display the agenda view of this day under the calendar.

Do you think it will be possible to do this with xamforms.controls.calendar? If yes how? I looked up the documentation and there's not much information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the [demo project](https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/blob/develop/Example/CalendarDemo/CalendarDemo/CalendarDemoPage.xaml) as suggested in the docs, there is a

```
 <controls:Calendar
                Grid.Row="1"
                Padding="10,0,10,0"
                SelectedBorderWidth="4"
                DisabledBorderColor="Black"
                ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
                StartDay="Monday"
                TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"
                TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue"
                SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
                SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
                DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}">
            </controls:Calendar>
```

`DateCommand` that appears to fire when a date is selected, as well as a `DateClicked` event

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to have a code example, i am a beginner and whenever i try to create a DateClicked function, it says eventHandler "DateClicked" with correct signature not found in type "folder name"

Comment: `public void DateClickedHandler(object sender,  DateTimeEventArgs args) { }`

Comment: Ok so the problem is that this method can only return void, but what if i want to make appear something under my calendar ?

Comment: all event handlers return void.  You put whatever code you want to execute in the body of the handler.

Comment: Yea but if i want to make appear the data from my agenda page corresponding to this date in this calendar page will it be possible ?

Comment: I have no idea how your app is structured.  But generally yes, there is a way to do this.  Use a custom event, or a delegate, or MessagingCenter, etc

Comment: What do you mean by `i want to make appear the data from my agenda page corresponding to this date` , what data ? Where you define the data ?